# OGG vorbis granule calculation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ogg

So I has really old game OGG files. It seems that game plays them in chunks. I had idea slam all chunks together for a full file.
That means headers aren't quite correct. Media players play it but jumpily.
So try I did try to correct them in visual studio c
[image]

So header type first to 2 rest 0 and 4.

Bitstream serial some random number to all (5EBB9150).

Page sequence number 0 until 60 something.

Checksum calculation(crc32) was taken directly from ogg source and recalculated. https://github.com/soundcloud/ogg/blob/master/src/framing.c

Segments look fine if calculated they point to next OggS.

So how does calculate this granule? It plays after I am done with but it crackles and pops sometimes.

```
Processing file "test.ogg"...

New logical stream (#1, serial: 5091bb5e): type vorbis
Vorbis headers parsed for stream 1, information follows...
Version: 0
Vendor: Xiph.Org libVorbis
Channels: 2
Rate: 22050

Nominal bitrate: 104.800000 kb/s
Upper bitrate not set
Lower bitrate not set
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 11392
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 11392
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 11904
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 11392
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 11904
WARNING: granulepos in stream 1 decreases from 172800 to 12416
WARNING: Hole in data (1176 bytes) found at approximate offset 392801 bytes. Corrupted Ogg.
WARNING: EOS not set on stream 1
Vorbis stream 1:
        Total data length: 388243 bytes
        Playback length: 0m:05.299s
        Average bitrate: 586.032184 kb/s
```

Comment: Have you looked at the samples and resulting concatenated `.ogg` graphically? If one sample ends on a steep downslope and the other starts with a steep uphill curve, it may sound a bit unpleasant.

Comment: Yea it happens. It is visible in audacity. Look at that granulepos.

Comment: Then your best option is probably to apply a filter to get rid of that unnatural transition from one sample to the next.

Comment: Not good enough. I wan to fix it in byte code level. By calculating new granulepos and writing new bytes in there.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the filter should be done programmatically

Comment: If you want to do it easily, just fade out the ending sample and fade in the next sample.

Comment: If I only know how

Comment: Just make a loop and multiply each sample with a fading value to the first sample and and increasing value for the next sample.